# Kernel of Matrix Exponentiation

Tags: lie-groups, matrix-calculus

Why the kernel of matrix exponentiation exp: $g\to G$, where $g$ is the Lie algebra of matrix group $G$, is a discrete subgroup of $g$? If it is possible, use undergraduate knowledge to answer this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. We use MathJax which is the same math code which is used for example in the LaTeX typesetting language. You are encouraged to learn it as it usually helps getting positive responses. I helped you this first time. Please let me know if I got something wrong.

Comment: The word “kernel” suggests that $\exp$ is a group homomorphism but, in general, it is not.

Comment: @MartinArgerami $\exp$ is a map from $(\mathfrak{g},+)$ into $(G,.)$. That's why I thought that the OP had in mind the kernel of this map, if it was a group homomorphis. What's the alternative?

Answer (score 2):

I think it stems from the fact that a matrix $X\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $e^X=1$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $\text{diag}(i2k_1\pi, \cdots, i2k_n\pi)$ where $k_1, \cdots, k_n \in \mathbb{Z}$.